# Iterator (loop variable) in Python

Tags: python, loops, variables, iterator

To practice and better understand the `for` loop, I have designed a function that computes the factorial of a given number. I get pretty much everything beside the role of the iterator (loop variable).

Here is the function I designed:

```
def main():
    print("This program computes the factorial of a number!")
    n = eval(input("Enter a whole number: "))
    fact = 1
    for factor in range(n, 1, -1):
        fact = fact * factor
    print("The factorial of {} is {}!".format(n, fact))
main()
```

When I run the program for the factorial of 6, the function prints:
`The factorial of`**`6`**`is 720!`

I'm looking to understand what role and relationship the input `n` given by the program user has on the iterator (loop variable) `factor`?

To test this out, I removed the iterator (loop variable) `factor` and replaced it with the input variable `n`.

```
def main():
    print("This program computes the factorial of a number!")
    n = eval(input("Enter a whole number: "))
    fact = 1
    for n in range(n, 1, -1):
        fact = fact * n
    print("The factorial of {} is {}!".format(n, fact))
main()
```

When I run the program for the same factorial of `6` that I used with the previous piece of code, the function prints:
`The factorial of`**`2`**`is 720!`

Why do I get two different answers when I ask Python to compute the same factorial number. Clearly, there is something not right with the latter piece of code, which I assume has something to do with the relationship between the input variable `n` and the iterator (loop variable) `factor`.

Comment: You're overwriting the original variable `n` by using it as a loop variable in the second version.

Comment: 1. There's a math.factorial function; 2. n is being overwritten by the for loop.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but important: for Guido's sake, don't use `eval`. `int(input(...))` is enough.

Comment: @bereal: Indeed.  There's a reason the old 2.x `input()` was scrapped.

Comment: Thanks bereal, Mark and Kevin for the clarifications. Makes sense. Heard about the potential consequences of using eval. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with your working code:

```
def main():
    print("This program computes the factorial of a number!")
    n = eval(input("Enter a whole number: "))
    fact = 1
    for factor in range(n, 1, -1):
        fact = fact * factor
    print("The factorial of {} is {}!".format(n, fact))
main()
```

Add a print (protip: this is a highly useful debugging trick):

```
def main():
    print("This program computes the factorial of a number!")
    n = eval(input("Enter a whole number: "))
    fact = 1
    for factor in range(n, 1, -1):
        print(factor)  # Add this line
        fact = fact * factor
    print("The factorial of {} is {}!".format(n, fact))
main()
```

You should see output like this:

```
6
5
4
3
2
The factorial of 6 is 720!
```

As you can see, the `factor` variable changes each time through the loop.  It takes on each successive value in the `range()` you specified.

When you change the loop variable to `n`, it's getting overwritten with these values.

Comment: So the iterator (loop variable) sort of protect the original value of variable "n", is that correct?

Comment: The value doesn't need "protection" as such.  You just need to be careful not to overwrite it.  Think of the loop as running `factor = 6`... `factor = 5`, ... etc. all the way down to 2.  If you use `n` instead of `factor`, the old value of `n` will be gone.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Appreciate the help Kevin. All the best!

Comment: Also see my answer. I will reiterate it here though. You are going from n to 2 with the current range `range(n, 1, -1)` by changing this to `range(1, n+1, 1)` it will allow you to go from 1 to 6 and get the correct output of `The factorial of 6 is 720`.

Comment: @RPBruiser: Multiplying the values from n to 2 will give the same answer as multiplying from 1 to n.  Multiplication is commutative and multiplication by 1 changes nothing.  OP's first example already produces correct output.

Comment: @Kevin I realize this, I am not saying that, what is happening is that his output is returning `The factorial of 2 is 720` because n is being overwritten because it goes from 6 to 2, that is why it is saying the factorial of 2, however if he were to go from 1 to 6 it will receive the correct output of `The factorial of 6 is 720` because n is overwritten to be 1 to begin with and only goes until the desired n value is reached. I was not saying his math was off, I was simply saying that the way he has his `range()` written is the cause for the bug.

Answer (score 0):

In your second program, by the time the function has run up to the print statement, n has been changed by the for loop. So whilst n is changing as you expect it to within the loop, by the time you come to print n it has been overwritten by the loop.

Answer (score 0):

1. Overwrite variable:

As user enter value is define in `n` variable. and in second example n is again define in for loop. so variable n is overwrite.
Check the is of `n` variable.

e.g.

```
>>> n = 6
>>> id(n)
160708724
>>> n = 2
>>> id(n)
160708772
>>>
```

2. Use exception handle during type casting when code is excepting value from the Keyboard.

e.g. Code want to number from the keyboard.

```
>>> try:
...    n = int(raw_input("Enter number:"))
... except ValueError:
...    print "Enter only number value."
... 
Enter number:99
>>> n
99
>>> type(n)
<type 'int'>
>>> try:
...    n = int(raw_input("Enter number:"))
... except ValueError:
...    print "Enter only number value."
... 
Enter number:test
Enter only number value.
>>>
```

3. Related to your second example: I just print the value of n

code:

```
def factorialGenerator():
    print("This program computes the factorial of a number!")
    while True:
        try:
            n = int(raw_input("Enter a whole number: "))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print "Enter only digit."

    print "\nUser enter value %d and its id %s\n"%(n, id(n))

    fact = 1
    for n in range(n, 1, -1):
        print "In for loop value %d and its id %s"%(n, id(n))
        fact = fact * n

    print("\nThe factorial of {} is {}!".format(n, fact))


if __name__=="__main__":
    factorialGenerator()
```

output:

```
This program computes the factorial of a number!
Enter a whole number: r
Enter only digit.
Enter a whole number: 6

User enter value 6 and its id 142415988

In for loop value 6 and its id 142415988
In for loop value 5 and its id 142416000
In for loop value 4 and its id 142416012
In for loop value 3 and its id 142416024
In for loop value 2 and its id 142416036

The factorial of 2 is 720!
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def main():
    print("This program computes the factorial of a number!")
    n = eval(input("Enter a whole number: "))
    fact = 1
    for n in range(1, n+1, 1):
        fact = fact * n
    print("The factorial of {} is {}!".format(n, fact))
main()
```

Your problem is that your are overwriting n at 6 to be 2, where with the new range you are overwriting it to begin with until you are at the desired n value.